# tabindex focus to call submenu using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, tabindex

I am building a vertical navigation which is placed at the left of the page.
and the navigation calls the sub menu by hovering. 
but the problem here is i wanna build this navigation could be **respond by TAB**.

The situation that i got is when i hover mouse to the navigation bar, the sub menu will ease in. but i want to use Tab to focus on the main manu then the sub-menu will ease in as well. But it is not working.

Can it be done with HTML and CSS???

Example: https://www.whitehouse.gov/

And here is my HTML code:

```
                <nav id="menu"> 
                <ul class="parent-menu">   
                <li >
                <a href="#" tabindex="1" >Home & Kitchen</a>
                <ul> 
                <li><a href="#" tabindex="2">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" tabindex="3">item</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#" tabindex="4">item</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#" tabindex="5">item</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li> 
                </ul>
                </li> 

                <li tabindex="2">
                <a href="#" >Electronics</a> 
                <ul> 
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li> 
                </ul>
                </li> 

                <li tabindex="3">
                <a href="#" >Clothing</a>
                <ul> 
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li> 
                </ul>
                </li> 

                <li>
                <a href="#">Cars & Motorbikes</a> 
                <ul> 
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li> 
                </ul> 
                </li> 

                <li>
                <a href="#">Books</a> 
                <ul> 
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                </ul> 
                </li>

                <li>
                <a href="#">Support</a> 
                <ul> 
                <li>
                <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li> 
                <li><a href="#">Forum</a>
                </li> 
                <li><a href="#">Deliveries</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">T&C</a></li> 
                </ul>
                </li> 
        </ul> 
    </nav>
```

And here is my CSS Code:

```
p, ul, li, div, nav { padding:0; margin:0; }
 #menu { 
 overflow: auto; 
 position:fixed; 
 left:0%;top:20%; 
z-index:2; }
.parent-menu { 
background-color: #0c8fff; 
min-width:200px; 
float:left; }
#menu ul { 
list-style-type:none; 
} 
#menu ul li a {
 padding:10px 15px; 
 display:block; 
 color:#fff; 
 text-decoration:none; 
 } 
#menu ul li a:hover { 
background-color:#007ee9; 
    }
#menu ul li:hover  > ul { 
left: 200px; 
-webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
-ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
transition: left 200ms ease-in; 
} 
#menu ul li:focus  > ul { 
left: 200px; 
-webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
-ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
    transition: left 200ms ease-in; 
} 
#menu ul li > ul { 
position: fixed; 
background-color: #333; 
top: 20%; left: -200px; 
min-width: 200px; 
z-index: -1; 
height: 100%; 
-webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in; 
-moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in; 
-ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in; 
transition: left 200ms ease-in; 
}
#menu ul li > ul li a:hover { 
background-color:#2e2e2e; 
}
```

Here is where i find tricky. the Hover here works fine. but when it comes to focus, it doesn't work.

```
#menu ul li:hover  > ul { 
left: 200px; 
-webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
-ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
transition: left 200ms ease-in; 
} 
#menu ul li:focus  > ul { 
left: 200px; 
-webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
-ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
    transition: left 200ms ease-in; 
}
```

Hope You Guys can understand what i am saying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use without tabindex as follows:

```
#menu ul li a:focus + ul {
 left: 200px; 
 -webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
 -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
 transition: left 200ms ease-in; 
}
```

chek this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/toz7n3ym/1/)

**OR** remove href from a, the reason when you use href it focuses on < a > not on < li >
check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/toz7n3ym/

Comment: Big thanks~ sorry for the late reply. But the problem here is when i use Tab, the sub-menu jump out,but when i tap the second times. i think the main menu lost Focus so the sub menu bar will ease out when the focus is not at Main menu bar. how to set the sub menu stop jumping back?

Comment: not getting your point, clarify this pont " **the sub-menu jump out,but when i tap the second times**." tap what on second time**S**? can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Hi as you can see from the origin code. I wanna build the navigation when use press tab to call the first level menu which is Home & Kitchen level, then when i press tab again will get my focus on the second level menu which are those items. then i can use enter to get in page that i want. but in the demo you have gave me, when the focus jump into 2nd level menu where you clearly see the border change, then the menu will ease out because the first level menu lost focus which means no ease in effecy anymore.   I hope you can understand what i wrote. sorry about my English

Comment: I think you want sub-menu to be visible however got clicked on any of it's item? but why you want this if the page switches on click of sub-menu item? anyway if you want so css does not affect parents on children's focus you can use jQuery for it.